Why does this if statement trigger regardless of the z rotation of the object the script is attached to?
        if(Mathf.Abs(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z) > 90 ||  Mathf.Abs(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z) < 180)
        {
            mySpriteRenderer.flipY = true;
        }
        else
        {
            mySpriteRenderer.flipY = false;
        }

Hello! I would like for the sprite renderer attached to this gameobject to flip on the y-axis when what is the right hand side of the gameobject when the z-rotation is 0 points anywhere to the left.
However, whenever this code is ran, the sprite seems to be flipped, even when absolute value of the objects z-rotation does not appear to be between the values of 90 and 180.

throw a debug log in for eulerAngles.z and see what falls out

Thank you for the response! It appears that eulerAngles.z is saved as a number from 0 to 360, rather than using negative numbers like what is shown in the inspector, so I changed my code to reflect that. The problem still persists however.

In general you shouldn't rely on eulerAngles!

if(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z >= 90 && transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z <= 270)
{
    mySpriteRenderer.flipY = true; // Object is facing left
}
else
{
    mySpriteRenderer.flipY = false; // Object is facing right
}


In general you shouldn't rely on eulerAngles! When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned
